# Ubuntu Server 22.04 autologin

Tags: authentication, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, ubuntu-server

Trying to get autologin working for Ubuntu Server 22.04
(Don't worry, this is for a radio project, not an actual server)

I have tried

sudo systemctl edit getty@tty1.service

and entering

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noissue --autologin myusername %I $TERM
Type=idle

but it did not work - it is still asking me for a username.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Line in config

```
# ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear %I $TERM
```

Yours (is that the line you have in your configuration file?)

```
[Service] ExecStart= ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noissue --autologin myusername %I $TERM Type=idle
```

Must be in the file you edit

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noissue --autologin myusername %I $TERM Type=idle
```

Comment: still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

**try:**

> sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service

**And change:**

> ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \u' --noclear %I $TERM

**for:**

> ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noissue --autologin YOURusername %I $TERM Type=idle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you're using nano on ubuntu 22.04 make sure to save (write out) the file before closing or your changes will not apply.

The key combo is `ctrl + o`